# Create screen saver in xcode for iPad

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios7

I am working on iPad application in xcode 5.I want to develop screen saver animation like windows screen saver.When my app goes in idle mode automatically my screen saver runs.
How can I do this. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: I have a suggestion for you. Don't use the terms "like windows, like android.." when asking help for apple products. The thing is we don't know what you are talking about most of the time.

Comment: what does _my app goes in idle mode_ mean? which mode is the _idle mode_?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want an app defined time to mimic a screen saver ? If so just have a timer and present a full screen modal view with your video/animation.